# Build hash array in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I am reading a CSV file that is seperated by blank rows.  Each section between the blank rows I want to capture in an array.  Where array would be something like the following.

```
array[section0][row0]
array[section0][row1]
array[section0][row2]
array[section1][row0]
array[section1][row1]
array[section1][row2]
```

The CSV file is formatted similar to below.

```
this,is,section,one,line,one
this,is,section,one,line,two
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
this,is,section,two,line,one
this,is,section,two,line,two
this,is,section,two,line,three
section,two,with,extra,commas,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
this,is,section,three,line,one
this,is,section,three,line,two
this,is,section,three,line,three
section,three,with,extra,commas,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
this,is,section,four,line,one
this,is,section,four,line,two
this,is,section,four,line,three
section,four,with,extra,commas,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I am attempting to get the array into `$section[sectionnumber][sectionrownumber]`.  But this is failing.

I get errors saying *"index is out of bounds"* or *"cannot index into null array"*.

I am sure it has to do with array initialization.  I just cannot get this to work.

```
$file   = "filename"
$path   = Split-Path $file
$import = Get-Content $file

#find blank rows
$r = 0
$blank = "yes"
$firstblank = "yes"
$sectionnumber = 0
#initialize section array
$section = ,@()
foreach ($row in $import) {
    if ($row -ne ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,") {
        #not a blank row
        if ($firstblank -eq "yes") {
            $blank = "no"
            $firstblank = "no"
        } elseif($blank -eq "yes") {
            $blank = "no"
            $r++
        } else {}
        #initialize array for multidemension
        $section[$r][$sectionnumber] = $row
        $sectionnumber++
    } else {
        #this is a blank row
        if ($blank = "no") {
            $blank = "yes"
            $sectionnumber = 0
        } else {
            $blank = "yes"
            $sectionnumber = 0
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $section
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell can do most of the heavy lifting for you if you allow it to. Meaning that's what you may want to do.

```
$import = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.txt' -Raw

$section = [ordered]@{}
$i = 0

# remove trailing consecutive commas from the end of each line, then
# split the lines at consecutive line breaks
$import -replace '(?m),+$' -replace "`r?`n", "`n" -split "`n`n+" | Where-Object {
    # filter out blank lines
    $_.Trim()
} | ForEach-Object {
    # for each text block create a new section with a nested hashtable,
    # then split each block into individual rows
    $j = 0
    $section["section$i"] = [ordered]@{}
    $_ -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {
        # split each row at commas and assign to a new record in the
        # nested hashtable
        $section["section$i"]["row$j"] = $_ -split ','
        $j++
    }
    $i++
}
```

Note that you need PowerShell v3 or newer for ordered hashtables and `Get-Content -Raw`. If you're limited to PowerShell v2 or earlier remove the `[ordered]` type casts and replace the parameter `-Raw` with `| Out-String`.

---

**Edit:** If you want just a simple list of lines where each line is prepended with section and row title you can simplify the above like this:

```
$import -replace '(?m),+$' -replace "`r?`n", "`n" -split "`n`n+" | Where-Object {
    $_.Trim()
} | ForEach-Object {
    $j = 0
    $_ -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {
        "section $i - row $j - $_"
        $j++
    }
    $i++
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but not quite what I was looking to achieve.  I am trying to write a good response. But "enter" trying to get to a new line on here submits the form. so I can't really do much with this comment to show additional information.  Do you know how to keep it from auto submitting this comment when I hit the enter key?

Comment: I posted more information as an answer because I couldn't figure it out how to do it as a comment